# Additional classes from variable on an element that has an ngFor attribute

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my ion-button that displays a list:

```
<button ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let task of tasks" (click)="gotoTask(task)">
```

and it generates:

```
<button class="item-block item item-ios" ion-item="" text-wrap="">
```

When I try to add a class this way

```
<button ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let task of tasks" (click)="gotoTask(task)" class="{{task.status}}">
```

It breaks and ends up as:

```
<button class="completed" ion-item="" text-wrap="" ng-reflect-class-name="completed">
```

which obviously doesn't look right.

What's the correct way to add classes to the button?

Comment: What doesn't look right to you? I `class="completed"` not what you want?

Comment: Ha you got it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be using the `ngClass` directive

```
<button ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let task of tasks" 
    (click)="gotoTask(task)" 
    [ngClass]="task.status">
```

Binding to class directly as the code in your question does, has issues on Safari mobile as far as I know.

If the name of the class to add/remove is statically known, you can also use

```
[class.someStaticClass]="booleanExpression"
```

`ng-reflect-class-name="completed"` is information Angular2 adds for internal processing.